# unit testing actionfilter on mvc

Tags: unit-testing, action-filter

I am trying to write a unit test for actionfilter. i wrote some code but i didn't know if it is true or not. my action result code is below:

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
 {
   if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
   {
      HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/kullanicigiris");
   }
 }
```

i add this actionresult top fo some controllers.

```
[AuthenticationFilter]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

i wrote a test code like this:

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void TestActionFilter()
    {
        const string expectedViewName = "Create";
        const string username = "deneme";
     //   MockRepository mock=new MockRepository();
        AccountController v=new AccountController();
        var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
       var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        context.SetupGet(p => p.User.Identity.Name).Returns(username);
        context.SetupGet(p => p.Request.IsAuthenticated).Returns(false);

        context.VerifyAll();

    }
}
```

i wrote this for success. i will also write one more for failed. Is it a true approach?